# PostgreSQL bug in window function on partition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table `t` that has the following data:

```
    name    | n
------------+---
 school     | 4
 hotel      | 2
 restaurant | 6
 school     | 3
 school     | 5
 hotel      | 1
```

When I run the following query, the result is somewhat odd.

```
select name, n,
       first_value(n) over (partition by name order by n desc),
       last_value(n) over (partition by name order by  n)
from t;

    name    | n | first_value | last_value
------------+---+-------------+------------
 hotel      | 1 |           2 |          1
 hotel      | 2 |           2 |          2
 restaurant | 6 |           6 |          6
 school     | 3 |           5 |          3
 school     | 4 |           5 |          4
 school     | 5 |           5 |          5
(6 rows)
```

Although `first_value` works as I expected, `last_value` works strange. I think the values of `last_value` column should be the same as `first_value`'s because the `first_value` is order by `n` descending.

Is this a PostgreSQL's bug or am I missed something?

The version of PostgreSQL is:

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                              version
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. The `first_value()` and `last_value()` functions work on the **window frame**, not the partition. The window frame, as per the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS), defaults to the start of the partition to the current row if no `frame_clause` is specified. That is just what you need for `first_value()` but for `last_value()` you should add `range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` to your `WINDOW` definition to look beyond the current row:

```
select name, n,
       first_value(n) over (partition by name order by n desc),
       last_value(n) over (partition by name order by n
         range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
from t;
```

Note also that this has nothing to do with ordering of the rows in the partition. The ordering produces the partition in a certain order (not surprisingly) and the frame-based functions then work on the window frame without knowing or caring about any ordering of the rows.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is one of the craziest bits of api design I've ever seen in a database. If I can use a `MAX` function which refers to the partition and then replace with another function I expect it to also work on the partition. That's just sanity.
Of course they need to keep this silliness for backwards compatibility now but can we have some alternately named functions that do the expected?